# Leaflet JS- Highlight on hover

Tags: leaflet

I created a simple web map and now I am stacked on how to use the highlight function on hover. I tried to use the tutorial on the Leaf js site, but when I am trying to call the highlight function under geoJason variable, it is not working. Basically I want the polygon to be highlighted when hovered. The popup is working just fine.

Here is my script, without the highlight function.

```
ar map = L.map('map').setView([43.0982, -89.3811], 12);

var googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3'],
    attribution: '<a href="https://www.google.com/maps" target=_blank> Google Sattellite Map</a>' }).addTo(map);

// Adding the geoJason file and styling it.
var myStyle = {

    fillColor: "#2c7fb8",
    color: "#f20b0b",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.55
};

// Alder district was a geoJason file and now it saved as js file.
var geojason = L.geoJSON(alderdstricts, {
    style:myStyle,
    onEachFeature:districtdata,
    
    
}).addTo(map);

// Function to bind popup to the geoJason data.
function districtdata(feature, layer){
    layer.bindPopup("<span class='headings'>District: </span>" + feature.properties.ALD_DIST + "<br>" + 
    "<span class='headings'>Representative: </span>" + feature.properties.Representa + "<br>"
    + "<span class='headings'>Contact Representative: </span>" + feature.properties.ContactRep + "<br>"
     + "<span class='headings'>District Population: </span>" + feature.properties.DistrictPo 
     + "<span class='headings'></span>" + feature.properties.Image)
};
```

I added all of my script above except the highlight function and that is where I am stacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([43.0982, -89.3811], 12);

var googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{ minZoom: 1, maxZoom: 20, subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3'], attribution: ' Google Sattellite Map' }).addTo(map);

// Adding the geoJason file and styling it.
var myStyle = {
    fillColor: "#2c7fb8",
    color: "#f20b0b",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.55
};

// Alder district was a geoJason file and now it saved as js file.
var geojason = L.geoJSON(alderdstricts, { style:myStyle, onEachFeature:districtdata,

}).addTo(map);

// Function to bind popup to the geoJason data.
function districtdata(feature, layer){

    layer.bindPopup("District: " + feature.properties.ALD_DIST + "
    " + "Representative: " + feature.properties.Representa + "
    " + "Contact Representative: " + feature.properties.ContactRep + "
    " + "District Population: " + feature.properties.DistrictPo + "" + feature.properties.Image)

    layer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
        e.target.setStyle({
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        });
    });
    layer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
        e.target.setStyle({
            fillOpacity: 0.55
        });
    });
};
```

I'm not sure what you tried, but this should work. It simply adds a "mouseover" and "mouseout" event handler for each polygon, as well as your pop-up. If this doesn't work, please let me know what errors/behaviour you get.

In general, it's best to provide details on what solutions you have already tried in your question. Also, just FYI, JSON is not a contraction of Jason, it stands for JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: It was a total success, Sam Spade, thank you! I tried creating a highlight function and then called it from geoJason as onEachFeature: highlight, which didn't work.

I edited your mouseover and mouseout function by adding fillColor. I set a color for the mouseover and then for the mouseout, I gave the same style color as myStyle.